# Storing blobs in external location using built-in CoreData option

Tags: ios, core-data, blob

I have managed objects that have image properties. Since storing large blobs in CoreData is a bad idea, I'm trying to use the built-in CoreData option "**Store in External Record File**" which you can see in the Data Model Inspector.

Despite enabling this option, I do not see any image data being stored externally. Judging by the size, it seems like they are still being saved in the sqlite file. What is the issue?

Comment: Why storing blobs in CoreData is a bad idea?

Comment: I should say large (100kb+) blobs.

Comment: If your Core Data store ends up quite large (which a lot of small blobs could result in), you can end up with lightweight automatic schema migration being a PITA. See this: http://hamishrickerby.com/2012/06/04/core-data-migrations-and-large-data-sets/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your store type is `NSSQLiteStoreType`, your attribute is `NSBinaryDataAttributeType`. You have enabled `setAllowsExternalBinaryDataStorage` and your object data size is larger then approximately 1MB.

- Objects that are smaller than 1MB are stored in the sqlite database.
- Objects that are larger are just a reference to a external file.

You'll find the (external) files in a hidden sub-directory at the same location as the persistent store.

```
<path>/<database>.sqlite
<path>/<your_database>_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/
```

Comment: WOW. You mean core data will automatically decide this. This is insanely AWESOME.

Comment: Yes, this behavior is tested with CoreData and iOS 5.1

Comment: @marcusg Thanks for sharing! Does setAllowsExternalBinaryDataStorage work with Transformable attributes?

Comment: @pshah I have not tried with Transformable attributes, however if you use a transformer that supports NSBinaryDataAttributeType as core data type I can't se why it should work.

Comment: @pshah - can you elaborate? An NSValueTransformer only exports a Class it is transforming (NSData when it comes to Transformable CoreData attributes). I can't make the "external store" work although my images are over 10MB each. The .sqlite store is 40MB after adding 3 entities which have 1 string and 1 transformable (image). I can't see any hidden directories near the storage file.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite2 does not allow size of BLOB data to be more than 1MB,However sqlite 3 allows larger BLOB.First check out which version of sqlite u r using.
And if ur file is in MB's i would rather prefer them storing in local database instead.

Comment: that is the way of storing larger files. Files are not supposed to be stored in a database anyway.